# oAuth/MGTwitterEngine for the iPad

Tags: iphone, oauth, ipad, mgtwitterengine

Hey I'm working on a twitter app for the iPad using the oAuth/MGTwitterEngine.

It works perfectly fine on the iPhone but when I'm trying to make it for the iPad I'm getting a bunch of errors.

I've talked to a couple of other developers and they are also having the same issue.

Does anyone know how to get it working on the iPad? Since it's the exact same code I've used for both the iPhone and iPad but it only works on the iPhone.

Here's the source code for oAuth/MGTwitterEngine that I've used.
https://github.com/bengottlieb/Twitter-OAuth-iPhone

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to find a new source code. That one has clearly some bugs in it. I digged a litle in the code and I see many mistakes that might not be that easy to correct. So I recommend you finding a new source.

Comment: Thanks! I'll see what I can find